# vertical scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout

I need vertical scroll view, to scroll between the fragments in a landscape configuration.
this is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment2"
            android:name="com.kevtech.dup.frag1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment1"
            android:name="com.kevtech.dup.frag2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment3"
            android:name="com.kevtech.dup.frag3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

the scroll view is shown horizontally. why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the appropriate `orientation` property on your `LinearLayout`. The `scrollbars` property on the `ScrollView` doesn't change the way the content is rendered; the layout of the content itself determines that.

For example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

If you don't declare an orientation, the `LinearLayout` defaults to horizontal, which I'm guessing is your problem.